# Counting django fields when value is True and displaying this count

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django with `Projects` and `Tasks`. A project can have many tasks, here are my models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    task_desc = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    due_date = models.DateField('due date')
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    task_desc.short_description = "Task description"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

I would like to show a count of total tasks and total completed tasks next to the projects. I have added the below to my admin.py to show a count of total tasks per projects:

```
def project_task_count(self, obj):
    return obj.task_set.count()
```

How could I also add a count of only completed tasks to the admin, and also replicate this approach to show these counts on the website, not just in the admin panel?

I have tried adding this to my model, but it dosn't work:

```
def num_complete(self, obj):
    return self.is_complete.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def project_task_count(self, obj):
    return obj.count()
```

if obj is a queryset of all tasks `obj = Task.objects.all()`

```
def num_complete(self, obj):
    return obj.count()
```

if obj is a queryset of all completed task `obj = Task.objects.filter(is_complete = True)`

Comment: Thank you, this got me back on track!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property method in `Project` like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name

    @property
    def num_completed(self):
        self.task_set.filter(is_complete=True).count()
```

And add that property in the [read_only fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) of the Adminsite like this:

```
@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ["num_completed"]
```